# How do I unset my default xdg browser?

Tags: browser, defaults, xdg-open, xdg, user-default

I want to debug a program's behaviour when the user has no default web browser set, but I'm not sure how I'd return to this state after setting one. I know that I can **set** my default browser via `xdg-settings set default-web-browser <value>`, but what if I want to unset it, i.e., make it so that I don't have a default browser?

So far I've tried running

```
$ xdg-settings set default-web-browser ''
```

Which resulted in

```
xdg-settings: no parameter value given
```

I also tried

```
$ xdg-settings set default-web-browser ' '
```

Which resulted in

```
xdg-settings: invalid application name
```

I'm using a minimal installation of Alpine Linux running i3 in X.Org.

Comment: `xdg-settings set default-web-browser ""`?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I tried that, but it complains about no value being given.

Comment: @Newbyte please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/620947/edit) your question and update with what is your environment, what you have tried so far and what is the exact result you have seen.

Comment: @thanasisp Does that look good?

Comment: You could also add the error message you get, especially if it was `xdg-settings: invalid application name` which means `xdg-settings` checks for existence of the value, into where it should exist (some /usr/share/ or ~/.local/chare or ~/.config etc)

Comment: @thanasisp Done

Comment: These are the [xdg-utils](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-utils). You could uninstall any file associations for url handling or html or anything simlar, using `xdg-mime`. Or find the `firefox.desktop` into `/usr/share/...` or elsewhere and remove it temporarily, to see what's the DE's failover behaviour for this. But I don't know if these or any similar approach fits to your testing, it depends on what you want to see.